# Time complexity of max char subsequence

Tags: time-complexity

This function returns the max char subset sequence. Example input and output are below. Can someone help with time complexity

```
function shortenString(str) {
    let result = str.charAt(0);
    for (let i = 1; i< str.length; i++) {
        const c = str.charAt(i);
        let j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0) {
            const charA = result.charAt(j);
            const charB = str.charAt(i);

            console.log(`comparing ${charA} to ${charB}`);

            if (result.charAt(j) < str.charAt(i)) {
                result = result.substring(0, j);
            }
            j--;
        }
        result = result + str.charAt(i);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sample input and output:                                                                                                  # abc => c 
# ccc => ccc 
# cab => cb 
# cba => cba 
# daacaaba => dcba

Comment: looks `O(n^3)` to me

Answer (score 0):

We can use the  Big O notation to calculate its complexity [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

If we look at the code we have to main loops - `for` and `while`

The for loop will do n iterations.

Meanwhile the while loop will do n(n+1)/2 iterations - which represent the sum of a series of n numbers. Its complexity is give by O(n^2);

Therefor the complexity of the code if n*n^2 = O(n^3)